# Blazor Web App (.NET 8): How to use a server rendered component, on a WebAssembly rendered page?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

Lets say i have a WebAssembly rendered page in a Blazor Web App (.NET 8):

```
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<ServerSideComponent></ServerSideComponent>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

And i have a Razor component with server side rendering:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of having a server side rendered blazor component, on a WebAssembly rendered page? I want the page to be rendered in WebAssembly, and the component to be server rendered.

When i try doing this, i get this exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot create a component of type 'BlazorApp4.Client.ServerSideComponent' because its
> render mode
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.InteractiveServerRenderMode' is
> not supported by WebAssembly rendering. System.NotSupportedException:
> Cannot create a component of type
> 'BlazorApp4.Client.ServerSideComponent' because its render mode
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.InteractiveServerRenderMode' is
> not supported by WebAssembly rendering.

Comment: That code is running on the client - so it can't server render anything. But, maybe you could call an api on the server to render the component and then use the returned html fragment in a MarkupString? Of course that wouldn't be interactive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly you cannot use components that are defined on the server.  The best approach is to have a page with its default behavior (no render mode specified so it will use server side render) and then from that page you called the two componets.

Then you can define your compoennts render mode, something like this:

```
@page "/counter"


<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<ClientSideComponent @rendermode=WebAssemblyInteractive />
<ServerSideComponent @rendermode=ServerInteractive />

@code {
   
}
```

Take into account that your ServerSideCompoenent must also be located in the Client Project and cannot access any server resources such as a database.  In case you need to access server resources you have to create a controller in your serverside project and call it from the client components as a web api request.